# Solve the system $x+y=\sqrt{4z-1},\ x+z=\sqrt{4y-1},\ z+y=\sqrt{4x-1}$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

> Find all real numbers $x,\ y,\ z$ that satisfy $$x+y=\sqrt{4z-1},\ x+z=\sqrt{4y-1},\ z+y=\sqrt{4x-1}$$

First natural move would be rewriting the system as:
$$x^{2}+y^{2}+2xy=4z-1$$
$$x^{2}+z^{2}+2xz=4y-1$$
$$z^{2}+y^{2}+2zy=4x-1$$
Thus,
$$2x^{2}+2y^{2}+2z^{2}+2xy+2yz+2zx-4x-4y-4z+3=0$$
And I tried to write the polynomial above as the sum of complete squares. Is this possible or do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that these equations are defined only for $x,y,z\ge 1/4$.

Consider the first two equations
$$x+y=\sqrt{4z-1}$$
$$x+z=\sqrt{4y-1}$$
Subtracting these two equations gives us
$$y-z=\sqrt{4z-1}-\sqrt{4y-1}$$
If $y\gt z$, then the LHS is positive but the RHS is negative, so this cannot be. Similarly, if $y\lt z$, then the LHS is negative but the RHS is positive, which is also impossible. Thus, we have that
$$y-z=\sqrt{4z-1}-\sqrt{4y-1}=0$$
or 
$$y=z$$
We may show by similar reasoning that $x=y$, and so $x=y=z$.
Then we have that
$$2x=\sqrt{4x-1}$$
or
$$4x^2-4x+1=0$$
Which has one solution:
$$x=\frac{1}{2}$$
This gives us the only solution to your system:
$$x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}$$

**NOTE:** This problem is trivialized by the fact that both $x$ and $\sqrt{4x-1}$ are increasing functions. The following system of equations might be more interesting:
$$x+y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4z-1}}$$
$$x+z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4y-1}}$$
$$y+z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x-1}}$$

Comment: Note that $$4x^2-4x+1=0$$ is $$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2=0$$

Comment: What if I am also looking for complex solutions also?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Oooh, that is a very interesting (and indubitably much more difficult) problem. That would depend on what branch of the square root function you use, I suppose. However, you should be able to do a trick similar to the one used in my answer, since the norm $N(z)$ on the complex numbers commutes with the square root function, so it can be used to "order" $\mathbb C$ and (I think) show that $N(x)=N(y)=N(z)$.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Clarification: $N(a+bi)$ is defined as $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN `What if I am also looking for complex solutions also?` You get an equation of degree $16$ in $x$, but which [factors pretty nicely](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+resultant%5B+resultant%5B+(x%2By)%5E2-4z%2B1+,+(y%2Bz)%5E2-4x%2B1+,+z+%5D+,+resultant%5B+(y%2Bz)%5E2-4x%2B1+,+(z%2Bx)%5E2-4y%2B1+,+z%5D+,+y%5D).

Answer (score 3):

**Solution.** $\blacktriangleleft$ Subtract every pair of the equation, we would obtain something like
\begin{align*}
y-z &= (x+y) - (x+z) \\ &= \sqrt {4z-1} - \sqrt {4y-1} \\&= \frac {4z-1 - 4y+1} {\sqrt {4z-1} + \sqrt {4y-1}} \\&= 4\frac {z-y} {\sqrt {4z-1} + \sqrt {4y-1}},
\end{align*}
then $y -z$ must be zero, otherwise a sum of two square roots would be negative, which is impossible. Thus we have $x = y =z$. Solve any one of them would obtain that 
$$
x = y = z = \frac 12. \blacktriangleright
$$

Comment: Kind of falling behind. $\colon \rfloor$

Comment: Nice! $(+1)$ $\space\space$

Comment: @Frpzzd Thanks for compliment!

Answer (score 1):

Necessarily $x,y,z\ge{\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$.

Without loss of generality, assume $x=\min(x,y,z)$.

Then $2x \le y+z$, hence
\begin{align*}
&(y+z)^2=4x-1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2x)^2\le 4x-1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4x^2-4x+1\le 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2x-1)^2\le 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2x-1)^2=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then $y,z\ge {\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, and $4x-1=1$, hence 
\begin{align*}
&(y+z)^2=4x-1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(y+z)^2=1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&y+z=1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&y=z={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Therefore $x=y=z={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.